# How can I save time to run sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I am a newbie and have very minimum experience to work with `php` and `sql`. I have tried the below code but it takes very large amount of time to run.

For each member of the students6 table, his/her Name and Registration number is collected from another table collegestudents and this process takes so much time that server gives

> 503 error

when students6 table contains huge amount of data. How can the code be changed
to accelerate the process?

```
$no1=0;
$zq1=mysqli_query($con, "select * 
                        from students6  
                        where CollegeCode='$college' 
                        order by UniversityRollNo");
while($zq2=mysqli_fetch_array($zq1)) {
    $xpa=mysqli_query($con, "select * 
                            from collegestudents 
                            where UniversityRollNo='$zq2[UniversityRollNo]' 
                            and CollegeCode='$college'");// 
    $xp1a=mysqli_fetch_array($xpa);
    $name=$xp1a['Name'];
    $rgn=$xp1a['RegistrationNo'];    
    ++$no1;
    echo "<tr>
            <td align='center' >$no1</td><td>$zq2[UniversityRollNo]</td>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$rgn</td>
            <td>$zq2[SubjectPaper]</td>
            <td align='center'>$zq2[Course]</td>
          </tr>";
}
```

Comment: it looks like you can join the two tables on `collegecode` and also possibly on `UniversityRollNo` - so rather than potentially thousands of queries you might manage in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do both queries in one JOINED query

```
$no1=0;

$stmt = $con->prepare("select * 
                        from students6 s
                            JOIN collegestudents c ON c.UniversityRollNo = s.UniversityRollNo
                        where s.CollegeCode = ?
                        order by s.UniversityRollNo");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$CollegeCode);    //<-- assumed that was holding the code????
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->get_result();

while($zq2 = $results->fetch_assoc){
    $name = $xp1a['Name'];
    $rgn = $xp1a['RegistrationNo'];    
    ++$no1;

    echo "<tr>
        <td align='center' >$no1</td><td>$zq2[UniversityRollNo]</td>
        <td>$name</td>
        <td>$rgn</td>
        <td>$zq2[SubjectPaper]</td>
        <td align='center'>$zq2[Course]</td>
      </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. it works fine. But there is one problem. Few members of students6 are absent in  collegestudents and naturally these members can not be obtained through this query. How to modify the query to include these students also (their names and registration will remain blank)

Comment: Make it a LEFT JOIN